# Opencv throwing a weird error running a simple program

Tags: c++, opencv

I compiled this simple opencv code:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"        
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"  
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

/*Compile using 

g++ -I /usr/local/boost CreateShares.cpp -o createShares `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` 

*/
using namespace cv;

class CreateShares
{
private:
    cv::Mat CoreImage;

    cv::Mat CoreImageR;
    cv::Mat CoreImageG;
    cv::Mat CoreImageB; 

    cv::Mat share0;
    cv::Mat share1;
    cv::Mat share2;
    cv::Mat share3;

public:
    CreateShares();
    CreateShares(std::string path);

    void showCoreImage();
    void showCoreImageR();
    void showCoreImageG();
    void showCoreImageB();

};

CreateShares::CreateShares()
{

}

CreateShares::CreateShares(std::string path)
{
    CoreImage = cv::imread(path, 1);

    if (CoreImage.empty())
    {
        std::cout<<"Could not read image !"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::vector<cv::Mat> temp_mat_vector; 
    cv::split(CoreImage, temp_mat_vector);

    //CoreImageB = (temp_mat_vector[0]).clone();
    temp_mat_vector[0].copyTo(CoreImageB);
    temp_mat_vector[1].copyTo(CoreImageB);
    temp_mat_vector[2].copyTo(CoreImageB);


}

void CreateShares::showCoreImage()
{
    cv::namedWindow("Core Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Core Image", CoreImage);
}

void CreateShares::showCoreImageR()
{
    cv::namedWindow("Core Image R", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Core Image R", CoreImageR);
}

void CreateShares::showCoreImageG()
{
    cv::namedWindow("Core Image G", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Core Image G", CoreImageG);
}

void CreateShares::showCoreImageB()
{
    cv::namedWindow("Core Image B", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cv::imshow("Core Image B", CoreImageB);
}

int main()
{
    std::string path = "/home/r/l33t/Secret Sharing/nature.jpg";

    CreateShares* cs = new CreateShares(path);
    cs->showCoreImage();

    return 0;
}
```

Then I proceeded to run it, but I got this weird error:

```
r@r-HP-Mini-110:~/l33t/Secret Sharing$ g++ -g -I /usr/local/boost CreateShares.cpp -o createShares `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
r@r-HP-Mini-110:~/l33t/Secret Sharing$ ./createShares 
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am pasting the gdb output till the error to help you analyse:

```
(gdb) next
[New Thread 0xb4af2b40 (LWP 17550)]
[New Thread 0xb40ffb40 (LWP 17551)]
65  s::showCoreImage()
(gdb) step
CreateShares::showCoreImageR (this=0x80516e8) at CreateShares.cpp:78
78  ", CoreImageR);
(gdb) step
79  G()
(gdb) step
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat


Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here ? is there something wrong with my code or is something wrong with opencv or am I not including some opencv path somewhere or is opencv not correctly installed ? I am out of ideas. Please help me !

Comment: On my system, when I run the program it works fine as long as I change the path to be an image on my system.  If I don't provide a path to an image that actually exists, then I get an error like you show.

Comment: When you split the image by channel, you assign each channel to `CoreImageB` not the corresponding channel. So your `CoreImageR` and `CoreImageG` remain empty, which can cause `imshow` to misbehave.

Comment: thanks man. I had messed up that path ..

Comment: Also, you can just say `CoreImageB = temp_mat_vector[0];`, etc.

Comment: @SchighSchagh actually the assignment operator wwas giving me errors, so I had to switch to copyto and clone. But let me check the empty issue you pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a datatype mismatch issue